# angular directive with dependencies testing

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I am trying to be a good developer & write some tests to cover a directive I have. The directive has a service injected in which makes a call to a webApi endpoint.

When I run the test (which at minute expects 1 to equal 2 so I can prove test is actually running!!) I get an error that an unexpected request GET has been made to my real endpoint even though I thought I had mocked/stubbed out the service so test would execute. My test looks something like the below:

I thought that by calling `$provide.service` with the name of my service and then mocking the method "getUserHoldings" then this would automatically be injected at test time, have I missed a trick here? The path of the endpoint the unexpected request is contained in the actual getUserHoldings method on the concrete service.

Thanks for any help offered as driving me potty!!!

```
        describe('directive: spPlanResults', function () {
            var scope;
            var directiveBeingTested = '<sp-plan-results></sp-plan-results>';
            var element;

            beforeEach (module('pages.plans'));

            beforeEach (inject(function ($rootScope,
                                     $compile,
                                     currencyFormatService,
                                     _,
                                     moment,
                                     plansModel,
                                     appConfig,
                                     $timeout,
                                     $q,
                                     $provide) {
                scope = $rootScope.$new();

            $provide.service('plansService', function () {
                return {
                    getUserHoldings: function() {
                        var deferred = $q.defer();
                        return deferred.resolve([
                            {
                                class: 'Class1',
                                classId: 2,
                                award: 'Award1',
                                awardId : 2
                            }]);
                    }
                };
            });
            element = $compile(directiveBeingTested)(scope);
            scope.$digest();
    });

        it ('should be there', inject(function() {
            expect(1).equals(2);
        }));
});
```

Comment: Does the directive have a templateUrl ? It's probably looking for it and that's the unexpected GET request you're seeing.

Comment: It does have a template url yes. Although the error referes to a GET for a path which is only specified in the service, the method I am trying to mock out, getUserHoldings.?????

Comment: I've added the path to the template html in another beforeEach, beforeEach (module('app/pages/plans/directive/templates/sp-plan-results.html')); but error still referring to the api endpoint path which is in my method on the concrete service.

Comment: Not sure about this way of mocking since I never tried it, I usually use `spyOn(plansService, 'getUserHoldings').and.returnValue(deferred.promise);`. After that I'm performing `scope.$digest();`

Comment: Yeah tried spying on as well, still seems to be getting the concrete service injected in and not the spied on version. I'm definitely missing something :(

Answer (score 1):

Referencing - http://www.mikeobrien.net/blog/overriding-dependencies-in-angular-tests/ - it would work if you did your '$provide' configuration in the 'module's context i.e. do something like -

```
describe('directive: spPlanResults', function () {

var scope;
var directiveBeingTested = '<sp-plan-results></sp-plan-results>';
var element;

beforeEach(module('pages.plans', function($provide) {
    $provide.value('plansService', function() {
            return {
                getUserHoldings: function() {
                    var deferred = $q.defer();
                    return deferred.resolve([{
                        class: 'Class1',
                        classId: 2,
                        award: 'Award1',
                        awardId: 2
                    }]);
                }
            };
    });
}));

beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile, currencyFormatService, _,  moment, plansModel, appConfig,  $timeout, $q) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    element = $compile(directiveBeingTested)(scope);
    scope.$digest();
});

it('should be there', inject(function() {
    expect(1).equals(2);
})); });
```